# Return multiple rows of an array from a mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have this in my functions.php file

```
function getUserOrders($userId){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM orders ";
    $query .= "WHERE userid=" . $userId . " ";      
    $odrset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  

    while ($odr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($odrset)){
        return $odr;
    } 
}
```

What I neeed to do in my orders.php file is display specific fields and their values from the returned $odr array as this snippet suggests

```
$userId = sql_prep($_SESSION['userid']) ;
getUserOrders($userId);
echo $odr['title'].$odr['orderid'].'<br>'
```

I am only able to do it in the functions.php file...

```
function getUserOrders($userId){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM orders ";
    $query .= "WHERE userid=" . $userId . " ";
    $odrset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    confirm_query($odrset);

    while ($odr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($odrset)){
        echo $odr['title'].$odr['orderid'].'<br>';
    } 
}
```

..and calling it in my orders.php file like so:

```
$userId = sql_prep($_SESSION['userid']) ;
getUserOrders();
```

which is not good since i need to recycle the function somewhere else and display different fields and their values. So I need to have $odr returned as an array in my order.php

Comment: Questions or issues with answers?

Answer (score 6):

Store it as an array and then return the array.

```
function getUserOrders($userId){
    global $conn;
    $query =
      "SELECT * 
         FROM orders 
        WHERE userid= ?";    
    $odrset = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($odrset, 'i', $userId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($odrset);

    while ($odr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($odrset)){
        $return[] = $odr;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

I've updated your `mysqli` connection to use a parameterized query with prepared statement. You can read more about these here, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php. This is the preferred approach than escaping.

Later usage...

```
$orders = getUserOrders($_SESSION['userid']);
foreach($orders as $order) {
     echo $order['title'] . $order['orderid'];
}
```

You may not need the `sql_prep` function with this approach, I'm not sure what that did. Your questions code didn't pass the `userid` to the function so I don't think that was your exact usage.

Comment: Just nitpicking, but should probably include the OPs `$userId = sql_prep($_SESSION['userid']) ;` as it looks like they have some minor sanitation, instead of directly inserting into `getUserOrders()`

Comment: @Sean true, I've update to use prepared statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_assoc only returns one record at a time so you need to store the results inside an array and return the array from the function:

```
// functions.php
function getUserOrders($userId){
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM orders ";
    $query .= "WHERE userid=" . $userId . " ";      
    $odrset = mysqli_query($conn, $query);  

    $results = array();
    while ($odr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($odrset)){
        $results[] = $odr;
    }

    return $results;
}


// in your orders file
$userid = sql_prep($_SESSION['userid']);
$orders = getUserOrders($userid);

foreach ($order as $orders) {
    echo $order['title']. $order['orderid'] . '<br>';
}
```